# Changing the `Proc` binding during invocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to change the binding of a procedure during invocation time?

```
class AllValidator
  def age_validator
    Proc.new {|value| self.age > value }
  end
end

class Bar
  attr_accessor :age
  def doSomething
    validator = AllValidator.new.age_validator
    validator.call(25) # How to pass self as the binding?
  end
end
```

In the code above, how do I change the binding of the proc during invocation?
Is there a way to pass the binding much like the `eval` function?

**Note**
If the example above were real, I would use `mixin`/`inheritence` etc. I am using the code to demonstrate my problem scenario.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000334):

```
class Bar
  def do_something
    validator = AllValidator.new.age_validator

    # Evaluate validator in the context of self.
    instance_eval &validator
  end
end
```

If you want to pass arguments (as mentioned in the comment below), you can use [`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000608) instead of `instance_eval` if you use Ruby 1.9 or Ruby 1.8.7:

```
class Bar
  def do_something
    validator = AllValidator.new.age_validator

    # instance_exec is like instance_eval with arguments.
    instance_exec 5, &validator
  end
end
```

If you have to make it work with Ruby 1.8.6 and below as well, your best bet is to bind the proc as a method of `Bar`:

```
class Bar
  def do_something
    self.class.send :define_method, :validate, &AllValidator.new.age_validator
    self.validate 5
  end
end
```

An alternative is to implement `instance_exec` older Ruby versions ([example here](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?instance_exec)). All it does is define a method before calling it, and undefining it after you're done.

Comment: Does that let you pass an argument to `validator`?

Comment: `instance_eval` has a sister method that lets you do that, see update above.

Comment: As a ruby n00b I love this answer. I have been trying to pass a proc from class A to class B. I then try to call the methods of class B in the proc. I can do this with instance_eval. Thank you.